# After effects (CS6) is 'disabled' when running AfterFX.exe -s argument

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

Writing my first script with after effects to automate some of my process. I want the script to run at startup of AE with some arguments passed via command line so I use the -s command.

Everything is done except for one problem, when I run AfterFX.exe with the -s, for example if i do this:

```
 "PATH_TO_ADOBE_CS6\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -s "alert('foo')"
```

It opens after effects and i do get that 'foo' dialog but for some reason After Effects is 'disabled'. What I mean is I can't do anything, not open any project, nothing. all options are grayed out.

Note that if after effects is already running, and I run the command, it doesnt 'disable' after effects and I get the desired result.

I am using windows and after effects CS6.

*note: obviously I intend to do something more complex than alert('foo') which was used a minimalist example to show my issue.*

Answer (score 1):

figure it out. for those who find this later, the solution is to add `app.exitAfterLaunchAndEval = false`.. i.e,

```
"PATH_TO_ADOBE_CS6\Support Files\AfterFX.exe" -s "app.exitAfterLaunchAndEval = false; alert('foo')"
```